# LWJGL 3 render to texture offscreen without display

Tags: opengl, frame-buffer

At the moment, I render everything in my OpenGL application to a single framebuffer (color only, no depth buffer). I then go from the texture ID and read out some data to use it. My problem is, in the init, I first init the GLFW window, make it visible calling `glfwShowWindow(window);` and then create the frame buffer. This means I have an empty window showing up where nothing is rendered.

But when I comment this line to keep the window hidden, the frame buffer status after creation is `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT`. How do I go about rendering offscreen without window, and is there a possibility to not use GLFW at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way I went by not showing the window seems the way to go, and the error about `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT`apparently wasn't related to this at all and is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if reading directly from the frame buffer can work when you are not using the GLFW window at all. What you can do though, is create a texture which you can pass to your fragment or compute shaders and draw on it. But then methods like glDrawElements() (if i remember it correctly) will not work.